# IIS- How do i test www to non-www forwarding

Tags: iis-7, seo

i am trying to solve www and non www url problem in windows based hosting, 
i have done some work as given below , but i need to check whether it is correct or not ,  it will solve my problem or not.
web site pages build using classic asp 
(shared) hosting on  IIS 7.0 with go daddy

my global.asax coding as follows

```
  void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string newUrl = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().StartsWith("http://itcorner.org.in"))
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.VirtualUrl"] != null)
                newUrl = "http://www.itcorner.org.in" + HttpContext.Current.Items["UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.VirtualUrl"].ToString();
            else
                newUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Replace("http://itcorner.org.in", "http://www.itcorner.org.in");



            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            Response.StatusCode = 301;
            Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently";
            Response.AddHeader("Location", newUrl);
            Response.End();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not Classic ASP but ASP.NET. Did you try the code out? Why not just use IIS UrlRewrite to do this for you?

Comment: yes i tried that code, and yes this code is in asp.net and site pages in classic asp, think IIS server support both,
and i cant use IIS UrlRewrite cause i dont have root access as this is shared hosting

Comment: Ok...so did the code above work? If this is IIS7 then your shared hoster should have UrlRewrite installed already.